# Is there any handy code coverage tool to be used with JUnit?

Tags: java, junit

Is there handy code coverage tool to be used with JUnit?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would imagine most code coverage tools can be used pretty easily with JUnit. Previously I've used [EMMA](http://emma.sourceforge.net/), which is good. If you're an Eclipse user, there's an Eclipse plugin called [EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/) to integrate things.

Comment: If you're using Eclipse EclEmma is definitely good and very simple to use.

Comment: EclEmma is very nice, but users should read the [FAQ about coverage of exceptions](http://www.eclemma.org/faq.html#trouble02) (in a nutshell, exception code may show up as non-covered even whan it is actually executed). If you find an apparently non-covered block, you can just run it in the debugger to see if it actually gets executed.

Comment: By "previously" are you implying that you have a new favorite code coverage tool?

Comment: @DavidHarkness: Not particularly - it's just a while since I've  configured one directly. The build systems I use now are somewhat different, and may or may not be using EMMA behind the scenes.

Answer (score 5):

Here are my preferences in that order:

1. [EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/)
2. [Clover](http://www.atlassian.com/software/clover/)

And here is a [bunch of open source tools](http://java-source.net/open-source/code-coverage) and with comparison.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Here you can find another comparison: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/Comparison+of+code+coverage+tools

Answer (score 2):

There are many and google is your friend.

[NoUnit](http://nounit.sourceforge.net/)

[Coverlipse](http://coverlipse.sourceforge.net/) (I would recommend this, but its an eclipse plugin)

[Codecover](http://codecover.org/)

Answer (score 2):

Cobetura http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/