# Code coverage for Java: dead or paid?

Tags: java, code-coverage, cobertura, emma, clover

I'm looking for an answer on code coverage tools.  I know variations on this question have been asked before:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904571/code-coverage-tools-in-java
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39329/what-is-your-favourite-code-coverage-tools-free-and-non-free
- [Code coverage tools in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518362/code-coverage-tools-in-java)
- [Is there any handy code coverage tool to be used with JUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269636/is-there-any-handy-code-coverage-tool-to-be-used-with-junit)

so it's possible this is a terrible question.  But for the most part those questions are *years* old, and I'm looking to see if there are any new tools that have emerged.

I am aware of:

- [Cobertura](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/)
- [Emma](http://emma.sourceforge.net/)/[EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/)
- [Clover](http://www.atlassian.com/software/clover/overview)
- [Semantic Designs](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/).

But as far as I can tell (see below), the two open source projects are essentially dead.  A paid solution is an option, but I'd prefer open source if possible.

Has open source essentially given up on innovating code coverage software, or has the energy gone into some new library that I'm not aware of?

**Cobertura**

```
Latest version: 1.9.4.1, released 3/3/2010
Last commit: 1/7/2011
```

**Emma**

```
Latest version: 2.1.5320, released 6/22/2005
Last commit: (uses CVS, so there are no changesets, but commits are 6-8 years old)
Developer forums have only a handful of posts
```

**Clover**

```
Latest version: 3.1.5, released 4/25/2012
```

Comment: An old last commit or version does not necessarily mean that the project is dead ; maybe it has reached a point where is does not need additional development and is considered stable. I still use Cobertura as an IDE plugin.

Comment: Cobertura is the one I've historically used, and it's generally worked well for us.  But my concern with projects with no commits or activity is who handles the bugs?  I guess it's open source, so maybe the answer is: me!

Comment: I guess so :) Or maybe you can get the bug fixed at a Hackaton event, where people gather to code/debug something ?

Comment: Yeah, that's a possibility too.

Comment: Or start a bounty for it on [FreedomSponsors](http://www.freedomsponsors.org) ;)

Comment: @Olivier Just use Java 7 language constructs and you'll see why it's a problem a product like Cobertura isn't updated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a open source code coverage tools that has been actively updated rencently.

JaCoCo http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/

It is by the team developed EclEmma, and SONAR is supporting it in recently years.  Sounds promising to me.

Comment: +1 Another tool is the one I develop, JMockit Coverage (which gets released as part of the JMockit toolkit). This tool brings (or attempts to bring) a few innovations: 1) "true" line coverage (where separately executable segments in a line of code are measured and displayed separately, rather than as a whole as in other tools); and 2) a *path coverage* metric.